# Using regex in Powershell replace string in single quotation marks

Tags: regex, powershell

considering this file

```
AppConfig = {
    version: '4.0.0',
    clientId: "guid",
    httpProxy: 'rest',
    restUrl: "http://url.contoso.com/v1/",

    conferences: ["lync", "hangouts", "webex"],    // "lync", "hangouts", "webex"

    dataRefreshInterval: 60 //seconds
}
```

I want to replace  the string inside the single quotation marks with another string. I want to change the value of the specific property (in my case `version`).

```
$content = Get-Content $VersionFile

for($i = 0;$i -lt $content.Count; $i++)
{
    if($content[$i] -like "*version:*")
    {
        $content[$i] = $content[$i] -creplace <replaceWhat>, <replaceWith>
    }      
}
```

more elegant way how to find the line with `version` is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to replace the text inside the quotes for version, you can do the following :

```
$content = Get-Content $VersionFile
$replacement = <ReplaceWith>
$content = $content -creplace "version: '[^']*'","version: '$replacement'"
```

It will replace `4.0.0` by `<ReplaceWith>` in you text

Comment: @pandemic: If you want to replace any string inside single-quotes, you'd have to do this for each replacement, because I guess the replacement text won't be the same for each item

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$version = "x.x.x.x"
$content = Get-Content $VersionFile
$content -replace "version: '(.*)'","version: '$version'"
```

Comment: You need to make the `*` lazy, otherwise it won't work. Your regex will match from `version` to `'rest',` here

Comment: What do you mean by making the * lazy? My code works but I'm ok to improve my regex ;-)

Comment: By default, the `*` is greedy. It means that it will match as many characters he can. Here he will stop to the last `'` of the text. Making him lazy is done by adding a `?` after it, so it matches the least characters possible.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm wrong, your regex still work. It is because `.` won't match newlines by default. No need for laziness here, my bad...

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation however in this case it works and does not replace all characters until the last `'` but only after the first pattern found which is `version: 'xxxx'`. Do you mean in others cases `.*` would be too permissive?

Comment: Ok you answered just before my previous comment. No problem ;-)

Comment: Yeah, as I said just above, `.` does not match new line, so it's not a problem in this case. If you want to know more about why greediness can be a problem, read this : http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap It will be far more clear than I am :)

Comment: Thanks for the link ;-)